# mobile navigation wont responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

Hey im working on a website for a client, however i think ive missed out something that is really annoying me atm.

http://www.enlock.co.nz/asp-web/source/index.html

here is the preview im providing for client as a small design mockup. You can notice that on web if you resize the page it will change and be responsive however on mobile it will display just as web does without changing to the smaller screen navigation.

also when the page is zoomed in on mobile it doesnt resize.

How would i accomplish this way of makig this change for mobile?

just so your aware i am not an extremely experienced web developer, i am still studying and was given this project by a family friend to do for them.

This is basically the same as what i have done for responsiveness, as shown in w3Schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For responsive websites you need to include this in your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

--- the responsive meta tag